# Strange java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

I have a strange problem in my application

Some users send me the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

i , myself , have never experienced that error. Here is the code:

```
         for(int i =0; i<length*2; i+=2) {
            if(charsLeft[i/2]==1)
                temp[i]=word[i/2];//IT HAPPENS HERE
        ....

        length = word.length;        
        charsLeft = new int[length];
        temp = new String[length*2];
```

When a users goes back to home screen , the application saves and later loads the data this way:

```
    public Bundle saveState(Bundle bundle) {
    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            bundle.putStringArray("word",game.word.word);
            bundle.putIntArray("charsLeft",game.word.charsLeft);
            bundle.putInt("length",game.word.word().length());
            bundle.putStringArray("temp",game.word.temp);
            bundle.putCharArray("characters", game.word.characters);
            ...                     
        }
    }
    return bundle;
}
public synchronized void restoreState(Bundle bundle) {
    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
        mPaused = true;
        if (bundle != null) {       
            game.word.word = bundle.getStringArray("word");
            game.word.length = bundle.getInt("length");
            game.word.init();
            game.word.charsLeft = bundle.getIntArray("charsLeft");              
            game.word.temp = bundle.getStringArray("temp");
            game.word.characters = bundle.getCharArray("characters");
            ...     

        }            
     }
}
```

Does anyone see where it goe

EDIT
full loop

```
 for(int i =0; i<(length)*2; i+=2) {
            if(charsLeft[i/2]==1)
                temp[i]=word[i/2];
            else
                temp[i]="_";
            temp[i+1]=" ";
            }
```

Example word[0] = a word[1] = n .....
        ->"answer"
the loop diveds the word in spaces and the letter or if the letter isnt guessed yet by a _
ex. a n s _  e _

EDIT:
I think I found the error :
A thread was calling the loop while an other thread could reassign word to another value , and if the loop was called before the value of length was changed then you have an error. 
I changed the loop to this

```
     temp = new String[word.length*2];
     for(int i =0; i<(word.length*2); i+=2) {
            if(charsLeft[i/2]==1)
                temp[i]=word[i/2];
```

Now lets hope its fixed

Comment: That loop is seriously confusing me. Can you make it any easier to understand?

Comment: add the explenation , hope u understand :)

Comment: In the first example you have `i<length*2` and in the other `i<(length-1)*2` which one are you using? And one more question, is `length == word.length`?

Comment: i<length  , and yes length == word.length

Answer (score 2):

Forget your loop if all you want to do is divide the word by spaces or blanks.  Just using split:

```
String[] words = word.split( "\s|_" );
```

That will spit the word into an array of words on either a space or an underscore.

Comment: but word.length should be the index range, no?

Comment: Changed my answer after you explained what the intent of that loop is.  Still don't quite have a clear picture from what you typed.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explenation , english isnt my mother language.

The application is an hangman
-word : contains the word the player has to gues , every index has 1 letter.
-charsLeft : is 1 if the player has guessed that letter
-Temp: displays the guessed letters and "_" for non-guessed letters divided by spaces

Comment: Not a problem. :-)  Just having a hard time understanding so my answers aren't that good.

Comment: oke , I hope you understand now that I cant use split , because sometimes temp need to be "_" instead of the letter.

I found the error strange because it doesnt happen all the time and i/2 wont be greater then word.length.
Since word.length is the array size index of word

Comment: It has something to do with the save load state because Its the first time I get that error and its the first time I save load the data when users go back to home screen , before I wasnt using threads